# Why does VS Code add data types to Python variables

Tags: python, variables

I am using Python 3.9.6 and VS Code 1.72. I have not used it in a while and I am finding that whenever i create a variable depending on what value i give it or what it is to be used for vs code will add something like : literal[4] or [str] before the equal sign, is this a new festsog Python, of vs code, i am confused as I know Python variables are not type specific.

Test = 4
Vs code changed to Test: literal]4] = 4

Comment: Python has supported type annotations (as a form of documentation) for quite some time now.

Comment: When you say VSCode "changed" it, do you mean you see `(variable) Test: Literal[4]` on mouseover or are you saying VSCode made that actual edit of you code?